# how to upload multiple artifacts in nexus2 using script

Tags: maven-2, nexus

Can someone provide an example on how to upload multiple artifacts (3rd party JARs) to a Nexus 2 repository?  I understand that we can use Maven cmd line to upload using the 
`mvn deploy:deploy-file` goal. But I did not understand it. Please explain with an example or with sample script on how it actually works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This script was written for Nexus Repository 3 but can likely be altered easily for Nexus Repository 2.

https://github.com/DarthHater/nexus-repository-import-scripts/blob/master/mavenimport.sh

This uses curl to do so with a bunch of Maven artifacts. Might be a bit simpler for you.

Comment: Thanks will try it out